# OR statement isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to Sqlserver and I'm doing something like

```
select *
from table1
where field1 IN ('textvalue1','textvalue2') OR field2 IN ('textvalue1','textvalue2')
```

It's not working at all... no syntax errors and an `AND` statement works fine.
I've tried enclosing it in parenthesis as well.

Comment: Use http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler and write code and link it and setup some sample data...

Comment: What is `list`? Is this a variable or a sub query or... comma seperated values?

Comment: You'll have to share some sample data and your desired results. All we can tell you from looking at your SQL statement is that it will run, which it will, but you already knew that.

Comment: Sorry its just a text value im trying to filter by.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what isn't working?  Are you certain that your fields don't have leading or trailing spaces so that they wouldn't match a `'textvalue1'` exactly?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your query... is it something silly like an apostrophe or comma is out of place?

Comment: When I introduce the OR, it will filter by neither field1 or field2. When I simply copy paste one IN statement it works fine. Ive tried this with both to check syntax and separately they do whats intended.

Comment: maybe try `('%textvalue1%','%textvalue2%')` for wildcard matching?

Comment: @Heather Please show some sample data.  As written, your query looks fine.  Have you tried doing something like `Where RTrim(LTrim(Field1)) In ('text1', 'text2') Or RTrim(LTrim(Field2)) In ('text1', 'text2')`?

Comment: Cant be it- they work without the OR in there. I attempted it with the ID number field and got the same results. Not sure how to accurately do some sample data, the data im using is sensitive.

Comment: @Heather Can you post EXACTLY what you are trying to run?

Comment: Ill try to do some sample data- essentially I have A LARGE list of text values I have to include in each IN statement. Around 40-50.

Comment: @Heather it may be cleaner for you to use a table variable and a sub query. It depends on how you are getting this list of values.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to all the comments, you must not have the values in your data that you think you do. Here is a reproducible example of it working.

```
declare @table table (field1 varchar(64), field2 varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('a','b'),
('c','d'),
('e','f'), --only row that won't return with logic below
('g','h'),
('i','j')

select *
from @table
where field1 in ('a','c') or field2 in ('h','j')
```

**RETURNS**

```
+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 |
+--------+--------+
| a      | b      |
| c      | d      |
| g      | h      |
| i      | j      |
+--------+--------+
```

**OF NOTE** SQL Server ignores trailing spaces for equality operators, but leading spaces will fail. Thus, you *may* need to use `LTRIM()` if you have leading space.

```
declare @table table (field1 varchar(64), field2 varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('a    ','b'),
('c    ','d'),
('e    ','f'),
('g','    h'),
('i','    j')

select *
from @table
where ltrim(field1) in ('a','c') or ltrim(field2) in ('h','j')
```

Comment: After looking back on my data I realized it IS working, its just a larger set of combinations between the columns then I expected... Your visualization helped me realize Im an idiot. Thank you!

Comment: No worries at all @Heather. It's the small things most of the time.

Answer (score -1):

*Either you are passing name as  Variable then use ' YYY' or if you are fetching using an inner query then pass the sub query inside the IN clause as mentioned below.*

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSON 
WHERE NAME IN ('jill') OR NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM PERSON WHERE NAME ='jake');
```